# c# Find the intersection of two lists<> and create a new list with merged properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have two Lists - A & B include {time, value}.

```
List<TimeVal> A = ...;
List<TimeVal> B = ...;

public class TimeVal
{
    public DateTime time {get;set;}
    public int value {get;set;}
}
```

How can I find the intersection where A.time == B.time to generate a new List which merges the properties of both C= {time, valueA, valueB} ?

```
List<TimeBothVals> C = ?
public class TimeBothVals
{
public DateTime time {get;set;}
public int ValueA {get;set;}
public int ValueB {get;set;}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: This question is very unclear as written, but even if it was easier to understand it would probably be closed as being too broad.  Please review [ask], do some research, *try something*, and then come back when you have a *specific* question.

Comment: Meh I understand his question lol, too bad I can't answer it now. And I don't want the negative downvotes so I'm not editing it

Comment: Ok I did edit it, remove your flags so I can answer lol

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
List<TimeBothVals> C = (from ai in a
                        join bi in b on ai.time equals bi.time
                        select new TimeBothVals
                                {
                                    time = ai.time,
                                    ValueA = ai.value,
                                    ValueB = bi.value
                                })
                        .ToList();
```